# Как передавать данные между скриптами в Java?

Tags: java, сокет

Есть два скрипта, один формирует переменные со значениями и типами. Как максимально быстро передать их другому скрипту с учетом типа и значения? Я рассматривал Unix-сокеты (локальные сокеты). Например сериализация-сокет-десериализация.  Может есть более правильный механизм передачи? Основное требование - скорость. Поток данных постоянный и большой.

Comment: сокеты/файлы/консоль, какие-нибудь библиотеки типа https://github.com/caplogic/Mappedbus

Comment: слишком размытый вопрос. что значит между скриптами, т.е. что вы понимаете по словом ""скрипты"? эти "скрипты" выполняются на одном компьютере?

Comment: Две программы, два разных jar. Да локально выполняются на одном.